# Magento customer login page redirects to itself without any error

Tags: php, magento

I'm having a problem whereby Magento will redirect the user to the front end login when entering correct credentials. This seems to only happen if the user has previously opened a different store view in the same browser. I have set the cookie domain in Magento admin to be the domain of each store view. I can clear the cache on the browser login to two stores and all be well until i log out of both then back into one and I'll get the problem.

Config is set to use SID on front end, but disabled i still get the problem.

Any suggestions? I'm using Magento 1.7 community edition.

Comment: Enable logs in System > Configuration > (Advanced tab) Developer > Log settings. Then just check your logs for any errors. You might find some errors there. Also check error.log of Apache or nginx. Lets us know if there are any errors.

Comment: Logs are enabled but all i see are old development php syntax errors. No errors are thrown upon seeing the problem.

Comment: Have you opened the developer tab in Chrome or Firebug in Firefox to view current cookies?  I would try deleting all cookies in the browser this way.  Sometimes an old cookie will reside and cause odd issues like this.

Answer (score 8):

Another situation that could cause the customer login issue is the missing `form_key` from login template.

In order to solve this please locate the login.phtml template in your theme 
Go to `template/customer/form/login.phtml` and `template/persistent/customer/form/login.phtml` and add the following code in the login form

```
<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>" />
```